# Como hacer para que no desapareza el value del input

Tags: html, jquery, django

Soy nueva utilizando el **typeahead.js** con **Django**. Estoy usando ademas **handlebars_min.js**. Cuando escribo tres caracteres se muestran los elementos de mi lista que coinciden con la búsqueda, al hacer clic, se pone el elemento en el `input`. El problema está en que cuando elijo el elemento y doy `click` afuera del `input`, el `value` del `input` se desaparece.

Aquí esta mi código

**Views.py**

```
def json_destino(request):
destino = request.GET.get('q', None)

if not destino:
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({}))

destinos = Clientes.objects.filter(nombre__icontains=destino)

vl = [{'name': c.nombre,'destino': c.nombre} for c in destinos]
vl = vl[:10]
ret = json.dumps(vl[:10])
return HttpResponse(ret)
```

Archivo **autocomplete.js**

```
$(function()
{
var engine1 = new Bloodhound({
    remote: '/destino/name/json/?standard=true&q=%QUERY',
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,

});

engine1.initialize();
$('#id_destino').typeahead({minLength: 3,highlight: true}, {
    name: 'destino',
    displayKey: 'id',
    source: engine1.ttAdapter(),
    templates: {
        empty: [
            '<div class="empty-message">',
            'No se ha encontrado ningun elemento',
            '</div>'
        ].join('\n'),
        suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<p style="border: 1px solid red; padding: 5px;">'+
            '<span class="text-primary" style="font-size:20px;">{{name}}</span><br>' +
            '</p>')
    }
}).bind('typeahead:selected', function(obj, datum) {
    taselected(obj, datum);
}).bind('typeahead:autocompleted', function(obj, datum) {
    taselected(obj, datum);
});

function taselected(obj, datum) {
    $("#div_id_destino").click();
    $("#id_destino").val(datum.destino);

}

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id=div_id_destino>
     <input type="text" name="destino"  id="id_destino" />
    </div> 
<script src="{% static 'js/autocomplete.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué le haces click al div?¿Por qué seteas el valor del input de id_destino, manualmente?¿Por qué haces bind con autocomplete?¿Y en autocomplete, que te está devolviendo datum?

Answer (score 2):

en la petición hacia `/destino/name/json/?standard=true&q` el json que regresas con `HttpResponse(ret)` no me parece que tenga en ninguno de sus items la clave **`value`**, como la defines aca:

`datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value')`

intenta cambiarlo por:

`datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('destino')`

lo cual hara que la busqueda en el campo de texto sea por `destino` o si deseas por `name`

en esta linea:

`displayKey: 'id',`

no logro encontrar la documentación para esa opción de twitter typeahead, estas segura que no es `display` en lugar de `displayKey`?

https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#datasets

---

te dejo un enlace hacia jsfiddle con un ejemplo para que puedas lograr implementar tú código mejor.

intenta poner él código de la función `taselected` para saber si no hay algun error ahí, y revisa la consola de tu navegador en busca de errores javascript.

https://jsfiddle.net/2myqtjeu/